# Facebook devel: creating events in the past

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm building a FB app that tries to create items in the user's timeline.

I use Javascript; if i call the `FB.api('action','post',{url:XYZ})` it runs fine, the url is invoked and the event is created.

If i try to call `FB.api('action','post',{start_time:"2011-01-25T22:23:16+0000",url:XYZ})` for a start_time in the past i get "Error occurred" and it does not work.

I would like to add events in the past showing them in the corresponding year of user's timeline ... what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to add events in the past showing them in the
>   corresponding year of user's timeline ... what am i doing wrong?

This seems to follow along with the normal Facebook GUI for trying to add an event in the past.

*`An event cannot have an end time in the past.`*